# Raising 2 to large exponents

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, exponent

I am trying to calculate large exponents of two such as the following: `2^48572234` (*note: this is an example and is not one of the numbers I am calculating). However, python's in-built notation for raising exponents is rather slow on this task:

```py
number = 2**<exponent>
```

It takes over 80 hours on my computer to do this task (using the above example). However, a quicker method may be `pow`. Here is an example:

```py
number = pow(<exponent>)
```

This totals up to 68 hours. But this is still too long, especially when the exponents start getting really large. Another way of doing this is with the `math.pow` function, but it errors out with `OverflowError`.

I also tried another approach, where I appended `n` amount of ones into a string, converted it to an `int` and added one to get the answer. This would be similar to the following approach:

```py
def genExponent(n): # generate large exponents of two.
    x = ""
    for i in range(n):
        x += "1"
    z = int(x,2)
    z+=1
    return z
```

However, this approach is equally as slow as the others at 72 hours with my example.

Has anyone got any ideas on more efficient algorithms?

Comment: Using your example, `2^48572234` would be a number that would require approximately 48 megabits/6 megabytes to store and represent (`2^X` requiring `X+1` bits). There's not a processor on earth that could calculate a number like this using hardware acceleration, so this is going to be done using software alone. As such, it shouldn't be surprising that it's taking a while to calculate.

Comment: To use that property, though, it would probably be easier to calculate this in a round-about way. `2^X` in binary is 1 followed by X zeroes, so instead of mathematically calculating it, another approach might be to construct that string and then parse it into an (extremely large) integer.

Comment: In the question I said I tried that*

Comment: With these sizes, you should consider working with an exponent representation anyway. What would you do with this number: add 1 to the result? it would have no effect.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't really want to do anything with it -- I just wanted to see if I could, and what the quickest option for calculating it would be.

Comment: Then maybe instead of a binary string, use a hex string. Mod the exponent by 4 and have the most significant digit be "1", "2", "4", or "8" (2^0, 2^1, 2^2, and 2^3, respectively). Then have the number of zeroes be the remainder of the exponent divided by 4. It will be a much shorter string and, potentially, much easier to parse.

Comment: Interesting idea, I will definitely trial it.

Comment: i wonder if a recursive function would be faster

Comment: @Abion47 how would I decide what the most significant digit should be?

Comment: @sciencepiofficial `Mod the exponent by 4 and have the most significant digit be "1", "2", "4", or "8" (2^0, 2^1, 2^2, and 2^3, respectively).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the hex approach I described in the comment:

```py
def hex(exponent):
    sig_exp = exponent % 4
    sig = 2**sig_exp
    zeroes = (exponent - sig_exp) // 4
    return str(sig) + (zeroes * '0')

x = hex(1234567)
ix = int(x, 16)

# Equivalent exponential operator
# ix = 2*1234567
```

It seems to run reasonably fast, though not necessarily noticeably faster than the exponent operator option (about the same, in fact). I've only tested it in an online repo that doesn't like it when I try to create a string/integer of the size you described in your question, so I don't know how it performs there.